# How to modify the content of a div with no id and no class?

Tags: javascript

I would like to modify the content of the div replacing it with "hello people". I have seen that you can modify a div if it has an id with `getElementById`, but in this case, there is no id at all. Just plain text inside a div. I want to achieve that in pure javascript. Any ideas on how to do this? thanks

```
<div>
    Welcome to the page
</div>
```

Comment: By using ``Element.getElementsByTagName()`` Read more on this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Comment: There are different ways. If the parent has an ID, you can do `parentID > div`. But without a context and knowing what's around, it's hard to tell more.

Comment: Use `document.querySelector` - provided you can write a CSS selector that can uniquely identify this element (hint: use `:nth-child(n)`).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to find the DIV element. One of them is using xpath. Try this:

```js
// Find the DIV
var xpath = "//div[contains(text(),'Welcome to the page')]";
var divElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, 
                      XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

// Replace text
if(divElement )
{
  divElement.innerText= 'hello people'
}
```

```html
  <html>
    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          Welcome to the page
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's the only div of the page, you can use:

```
myDiv = document.querySelector("div")
```

And then you can change the text with:

```
myDiv.innerHTML = "hello people"
```

Edit: If it's not the only div, it's possible to get a reference of it if it's the first or last of many divs in the page, for example:

```
myDiv = document.querySelector("div :last-of-type")
myDiv = document.querySelector("div :first-of-type")
```

Otherwise, there are many other ways to do this, for example if it's a direct child of another element you can get a reference of. You can check a list of (also advanced) selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: But what if there's more than one div in the whole page? The probability of such a case seems high to me

Comment: @JeremyThille I agree, but his is probably a quick exercise he's doing to use querySelector like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) to retrieve the node :

```js
var divs = document.evaluate("//div[contains(text(), 'Welcome to the page')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
var div = divs.iterateNext();

if (div) {
  div.innerHTML = "hello people";  
}
```

```html
<div>
  Welcome to the page
</div>
```